# XAML predefined types (eg. x:Double)

Tags: wpf, xaml

So, what's wrong here... In a WPF app, within a ResourceDictionary I have defined x-namespace:

```
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
```

then I'm trying to instantiate a double:

```
 <x:Double x:Key="BorderWidth">30</x:Double>
```

But it doesn't there's a compile-time error indicating that x:Double is not supported.

For the record, the following works (if I have sys-namespace mapped to mscorlib):

```
<sys:Double x:Key="BorderWidth">30.0</sys:Double>
```

Comment: It depends upon which variant of XAML you're using. Mapping to a CLR namespace for primitive types is the approach you must take with Silverlight, for example.

Comment: Aah, so you're using the 2006 namespace. See my answer below as to why the primitives won't work.

Comment: Adding namespace xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"  and using <sys:Double x:Key="BorderWidth">30.0</sys:Double> works fine in WPF project .NET 4.0 Visual Studio 2017.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Built-in primitive types for XAML are only available in the XAML 2009 namespace (http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml). If you're using the 2006 namespace (http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml), these primitives won't be available. MSDN's article on XAML primitives has a good explanation:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee792002(v=vs.110).aspx

**Edit**: There's an additional caveat:

> In WPF, you can use XAML 2009 features but only for XAML that is not
>   markup-compiled. Markup-compiled XAML for WPF and the BAML form of
>   XAML do not currently support the XAML 2009 keywords and features. A
>   scenario where you can use XAML 2009 features together with WPF is if
>   you author loose XAML and you then load that XAML into a WPF runtime
>   and object graph with XamlReader.Load. The WPF
>   System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader and its Load can process XAML 2009
>   language keywords and features into a valid object graph
>   representation.

If you're compiling your XAML, these primitives still won't work, so you'll have to map a "system" namespace to `System/mscorlib` as you already have done in the example provided in your question.

Also, given the context of your resource key, `BorderWidth`, you might not be able to use `Double` for your intended purpose. See Chris W's answer (which I shouldn't have downvoted, I'm really sorry!)

Comment: James, I don't get it. If I tweak my XAML namespaces, changing 2006 to 2009, it won't compile... I'm on VS2013, .NET 4.0. (.NET 4.5 installed)

Comment: Aah, there's an additional caveat. Updating my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

Ya these are weird and can screw with you easily. What you're trying to use it for actually isn't just one Double, it's four, for Top, Right, Left, Bottom, respectively.

So instead of sys:Double you're going to want to use `Thickness` instead like;

```
<Thickness x:Key="BorderWidth">30</Thickness>
```

Hope this helps, cheers.

Comment: While this makes sense in terms of the context provided by the asker's resource key, this doesn't directly answer the question. He/she's wondering why creating a Double from the `x:` namespace doesn't compile; this is only a valid approach with certain runtimes.

Comment: @JamesWright I would disagree unless you have a technical example of your argument. I could add the namespace he's looking for at something like `xmlns:sys="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib"` if it makes you feel better though. Regardless however, I would assume the OP is actually more interested in accomplishing his goal the question conveys. It's also not a nuance worthy of a down-vote in my opinion but I respect that you at least attempted to give an explanation but whatever's clever.

Comment: Take a look at this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee792002(v=vs.110).aspx. The `x` namespace primitives are only available in XAML 2009, so if the asker is trying to use these types in an earlier version, they won't be found, thus the solution/assembly won't compile.

Comment: Ya, I was more concerned with fixing his perceived problem than explaining the folly. So you got me there, though I do think your communication could use a little more tact.

Comment: Sorry, I was probably a bit too hasty to downvote, and now I can't undo it. Lesson learnt.